# I can't get html5shiv working?

Tags: html, html5shiv

For some reason, it just won't work for me in IE at all. It's in the head tag. I added the CSS. Nothing.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        document.createElement("header");
    });

<style>header,nav,article,footer,section,aside,figure,figcaption{display:block}</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could try this? `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: Try to include it from a CDN and see what happens - `<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to append that HEADER element to the DOM:

```
var elem = document.createElement( 'header' );
elem.innerHTML = 'The header';
document.body.appendChild( elem );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dW9Ak/

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to close that script tag too. Although as Šime Vidas says, you do also need to append the created element to the DOM.

Also, are you testing this in IE itself, or in IE Tester? I spent ages trying to get html5shiv to work in IE7 in IE Tester, only to find that it seems to be working ok in IE7 itself. In the process, I discovered that you can make IE8 and IE9 render as earlier versions of IE using an HTML  tag, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;">
```

More info about the above meta tag [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx).