# HTML5 html5shiv and IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5shiv

I am trying to make IE7 render HTML5 using `html5shiv`; I thought `html5shiv` would fix these issues.  However, Internet Explorer's debugbar is still griping about HTML5 tags.

[image: debugbar_output]

How can I fix this using `html5shiv` to use the same HTML5 content without errors in debugbar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
   See this page for language codes:
   http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/langtagscript.html
-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Page Template</title>
    <!--
         html5shiv via CDN
         Provides HTML5 support in hateful IE versions
         CDN: http://cdnjs.com/
    -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
    <header>
      <h1><a href="#">Standard HTML5 Page</a></h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="featured">
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1><a href="#">Title Foo1</a></h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
      </article>
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1><a href="#">Title Foo2</a></h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id="ads">
      <a href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com/">Get a better job!</a>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <p>Insert footer info here</p>
    </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the DebugBar is a third-party add-on to IE; Given that what you're doing is an IE hack, the DebugBar may not be accurately reporting what IE is actually doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't. html5shiv only makes it possible to style those elements. IE7 still won't know about them.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had problems getting html5shiv to work in IE Tester (assuming you're using IE Tester), which I found do not occur when I force IE8 to emulate IE7 using a  tag, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;">
```

(See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12077879/180500)). Based on this experience, I suspect IE Tester might have a problem with html5shiv: it might be worth testing your page in actual IE7 to make sure there really is a problem here.